# Why do I get this python MS sql server Error?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, dataframe

I keep getting the same error below when trying to write from a pandas data frame to MS sql server. I have triple checked that all my data matches the data types on the table.

Sample Data:

| POSTING_DATE | SOURCE | READTYPE | PPTAGID | ETAGID_PLATE | EQUIPID | AGENCY | ENTRY_PLAZA | ENTRY_DATE | EXIT_PLAZA | EXIT_DATE | TOLL_CLASS | MILES | TOLL_AMOUNT | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-06 00:00:00 | ELITE | Transponder | 777777777 | 11111111111 | 5363 | KTA | Eastern Entrance | 2022-06-04 17:52:39 | Southern Entrance | 2022-06-04 21:50:25 | 5 | 0.00 | 31.95 | 111111111111111111111 |
| 2022-06-06 00:00:00 | EZPass | Transponder | 777777777 | 11111111111 | 5363 | DelDOT | NaN | NaN | D95 | 2022-06-03 03:08:21 | 5 | 0.00 | 9.00 | 111111111111111111111 |
| 2022-06-06 00:00:00 | EZPass | Transponder | 777777777 | 11111111111 | 5363 | NJTP | 1 | 2022-06-03 03:27:38 | 2 | 2022-06-03 03:39:56 | 5 | 0.00 | 4.60 | 111111111111111111111 |
| 2022-06-06 00:00:00 | ELITE | Transponder | 777777777 | 11111111111 | 5362 | KTA | Wichita: I-135 I-235 47th St | 2022-06-04 15:21:21 | Southern Entrance | 2022-06-04 15:47:57 | 5 | 0.00 | 5.05 | 111111111111111111111 |
| 2022-06-06 00:00:00 | ELITE | Transponder | 777777777 | 11111111111 | 5357 | OTA | WR-BGCBN | 2022-06-05 02:05:25 | WR-STLINE | 2022-06-05 02:38:17 | 5 | 0.00 | 9.20 | 111111111111111111111 |
| 2022-06-06 00:00:00 | ELITE | Transponder | 777777777 | 11111111111 | 5355 | OTA | HEB-NWCLML | 2022-06-03 07:10:36 | HEB-NWCLML | 2022-06-03 07:10:36 | 5 | 0.00 | 3.95 | 111111111111111111111 |

Table Structure:

```
[PostingDate]  datetime,
[Source]       varchar(50),
[ReadType]     varchar(50),
[PPTagID]      varchar(10),
[ETagID_Plate] varchar(12),
[EquipID]      varchar(4),
[Agency]       varchar(10),
[Entry_Plaza]  varchar(50),
[Entry_Date]   datetime,
[Exit_Plaza]   varchar(50),
[Exit_Date]    datetime,
[Toll_Class]   varchar(5),
[Miles]        numeric(18, 2),
[Toll_Amount]  numeric(18, 2),
[ID]           varchar(50)
```

Python Code:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    try:
        MsExe.execute("""
            INSERT INTO test_tolls_table_temp (PostingDate, Source, ReadType, PPTagID, ETagID_Plate, EquipID, Agency, Entry_Plaza, Entry_Date, Exit_Plaza, Exit_Date, Toll_Class, Miles, Toll_Amount, ID)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            """, row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15])

except Exception as exception:
    print(exception)
    break
```

Error:

> ```
> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) 
> protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 9 (""): The supplied value is 
> not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for 
> invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type 
> with scale greater than precision. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)')
> ```

Comment: What is `MsExe.execute`? That's not a Pandas function. The code you posted seems to be doing what the slowest version of `df.to_sql` would do - execute INSERTs one by one without batching. Have you tried renaming the dataframe column and calling `df.to_sql('test_tolls_table_temp',engine);` ? If you use `engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_url, fast_executemany=True)` you'll get far better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Neither*** need to specify each column individually by like `row[1]`,`row[2]`...`row[15]`, ***nor*** a loop

***but*** use directly **`executemany`** (which's also more performant for DML operations than `execute` ) such as

```py
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

con = pyodbc.connect(
    "DRIVER=ODBC Driver xx for SQL Server;"
    "SERVER=<IP>,<some number>;"
    "DATABASE=DB123;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)


data = pd.read_csv(pathToFile,delimiter= ';') # is just a sample delimiter representation, you should replace with yours 
df = data.values.tolist()

MsExe=con.cursor()
try:
    MsExe.fast_executemany = True
    MsExe.executemany("""
                         INSERT INTO test_tolls_table_temp (PostingDate, Source, ReadType, PPTagID, ETagID_Plate, EquipID, Agency, Entry_Plaza, Entry_Date, Exit_Plaza, Exit_Date, Toll_Class, Miles, Toll_Amount, ID)
                         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                      """,df)
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception)

MsExe.close()
con.commit()
con.close();
```

Comment: Hello! Appreciate the help unfortunately. I received this error when implementing that approach. "The second parameter to executemany must be a sequence, iterator, or generator"

Comment: Hi @user17936622 . I don't know how you derive `df`, but presumably should be a a dataframe returned from pandas library, Considering that fact, can you please retry by replacing `df` with `df.tolist()`

Comment: I derive the df from a csv. by first reading the csv with "data = pd.read_csv(filepath)" then converting to a pandas dataframe with "df = pd.DataFrame(data)". I attempted what you recommended but received an error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'" so I did "df.values.tolist()" which worked but then received the originally stated error.

Comment: @user17936622 Then, use this `data = pd.read_csv(pathToFile,delimiter= ';')
df = data.values.tolist()` where delimiter depends on your current one within the .csv file. Just edited the answer.

Comment: This approach took me to the error "'The SQL contains 15 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'"

Comment: Have you checked whether the delimiter is right for you @user17936622

Comment: Why iterate and explicitly insert rows? `engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_url, fast_executemany=True)` works since 2019

Comment: Could you please elaborate